# How can I make a tree with n number of child nodes?

Tags: c++

Usually they have only two, but I need to make an object were there are a random number of pointers.
To represent this image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myTbh.jpg)

Using what I know I made this:

```
struct tree{
    string name;
    list<struct pointer> pointers,

    tree(int x){
        name= x;
        pnext=null;
    }
} root1;

struct pointer{
    struct tree *pnext;
};
```

A tree or object with a list of pointers and the structure for the pointers, but I doesn´t seem right.
How can I make a tree with a random number of pointers?
(I should say what is wrong with but I don´t een know were to start, sorry)

Comment: You can have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<node>>` in each node that represents the n children.

Comment: Read one of [these textbooks on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: a tree or a list?

Comment: a tree with a random number of pointers, lazy coder

Comment: `but I doesn´t seem right` Why not? Seems just fine to me (except I would not use `std::list` unless there is a good reason to do so). Why do you want *"random number of pointers"*?

Comment: user2079303, because in the image one node is linked to one, two or for other child nodes.

Comment: You could just as well have one pointer to an array of children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#include <vector>

struct person {
    string name;

    vector<person> children;

    person(string iName, vector<person> iChildren) {
        name = iName;
        children = iChildren;
    }
}
```

This way, each person has a name, and a vector with all of it's children in it.